# Give forms a name with Macro in excel

Tags: forms, vba, excel

At the moment I have a project with about 20 forms and sometimes I want to make small adjustments to them. So I created a piece of code to delete the forms and then recreate them the way I want.

The problem is that one line of code keeps giving me *Path/File access error (Error 75)*.

This is a small piece of the code:

```
Sub makeForm(formName As String)

    Dim form As Object

    'These lines delete the old form
    Set form = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(formName)
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove VBComponent:=form    

    'This line creates the new form
    Set form = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm)

    'These lines give the new form a few properties
    With form
        .Properties("Name") = formName 'This is the line of code that gives the error
        .Properties("Caption") = formName
        .Properties("Width") = 320
        .Properties("Height") = 242
    End With

End Sub
```

Can someone please tell me how I can make sure this error no longer appears? By the way, this error also appears when I manually want to change the name of a form after this macro failed, but doesn't when I do it before the macro failed.

PS: I'm new to this site so sorry if I made any rookie mistakes.

Comment: According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264531(v=vs.60).aspx) you can not make design changes inside a document. Why aren't you just renaming the existing form?

Comment: Why not just change the properties of the existing form?

Comment: I need to be able to retrieve the forms to use them. At the moment I use the names to make sure I retrieve the right one so it's required I give the new forms the name I want.

Answer (score 0):

Saving the workbook after you've removed the userform seems to clear the error.

```
'These lines delete the old form
Set form = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(formName)
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove VBComponent:=form
Set form = Nothing

ThisWorkbook.Save
```

I guess Excel refreshes some internal values when it saves.

Comment: It takes a long time to execute, but it works. Thanks for the help!